# Check for x value or similar on AJAX with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, string, json

Good day **stackoverflow**'ers

I'm doing a simple AJAX form, imagine some kind of registration.

This form posts the value to a PHP file which posts this to a database and returns a string like this one "**success id:12345**". I want this script to read JSON and check ID, success and so, the current code is:

```
// Some pieces of code 
        success: function(data){
            var reponse = $.trim(data);
            if (reponse.toLowerCase().indexOf("yes") >= 0){
                // check the id (Don't know how)
                alert("Your id is "+id);
            }else{
                alert(reponse);
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What format is your data being returned in?

Comment: make your life easier by returning an json object. so you can return sucess: true/false AND your id.

Comment: You need to return the data from your file you reference in your ajax call as a JSON Object. use json_encode. Then, in your success function, you can actually use data.id to get the ID.

Comment: return a JSON object {"success":true,"ID":12345} or similar

Comment: Yes @Ohgodwhy, that was exactly what I'm now thinking of. How can I pass the JSON thru jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP:

```
$response = array(
  "success" => true, 
  "id"      => 1234
);
```

Then `json_encode($response);`

The browser will get this...

```
{
  "success" : true,
  "id"      : 1234
}
```

You can make the ajax request and jQuery will parse the JSON for you.

```
$.getJSON("path/to/something.php", {var1: 1, var2: 2}, function(json){
  if(json.success){
    alert("Your id is " + json.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. This is also the proper way to return and retrieve and work with JSON encoded objects/arrays. I don't know how this doesn't have a "check mark" and more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to pull out the numeric id as follows:

```
var id = null;

if (reponse.toLowerCase().indexOf("success") != -1){
   id = reponse.match(/\bid\:([0-9]+)/)[1];
}

alert(id);
```

There are probably more efficient ways to generate and parse server results, however.

Comment: `reponse.toLowerCase().indexOf("success") != -1` .. the index could very well be 0.

Comment: Good point! Pulled the `>=` from the question--I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: `indexOf` returns the index on success and -1 on failure. 0 would indicate that the string does contains the substring. `>= 0` is fine.